# Delphi Adds the same item with for loop

Tags: delphi

Hey guy's so am making this program in delphi that loads a list of usernames i want to add them all to the Memo without using selectall i want to use the for loop to learn how it works as you can see i tried by failed it selects both but only adds the last one which is weird xD Any help would be great thanks guys

[image: The Error Image]

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
 Memo1.Lines.Clear;
 Listbox1.Items.LoadFromFile('names.txt');
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
 I: Integer;
begin

for I:=Listbox1.Items.Count-1 downto 0 do
begin
 ListBox1.ItemIndex:=I;

 Memo1.Lines.Add(ListBox1.Items.Strings[1]);
 end
 end;
 end; 
 end.
```

Comment: Do you have a typo in "Memo1.Lines.Add(ListBox1.Items.Strings[1]"?  Shouldn't the '1' be an 'I'?

Comment: X.X I feel so stupid of the typo xD ty for telling

Comment: This why some people advocate against using single-character variable names, especially `I` because it looks too much like `1`.  `Index` would be a more meaningful variable name, for instance.

Comment: the problem is usually more encountered with `1` and `l`. However with syntax highlighting the OP should have seen it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you add the item with index 1 every time. You presumably mean:

```
for I:=Listbox1.Items.Count-1 downto 0 do
  Memo1.Lines.Add(ListBox1.Items[I]);
```

This adds in reverse order. If you want the items in the same order it is simply:

```
Memo1.Lines.Assign(ListBox1.Items);
```

Comment: Gonna make this an answer ty bro need to wait 7 mins